# Deploying Grails application on Glassfish 4 error

Tags: grails, glassfish

i'm trying to deploy Grails application on Glassfish 4 but it was failed and got the below error :

```
Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.. Please see server.log for more details.]]
```

I can't figure out what is causing this error , i tried on google but nothing useful

Answer (score 1):

in the `DataSource.groovy` commented `driverClassName` and `dialect` in the whole file , in the `production` section i commented `URL`  and used instead the `URL` the `jndiName` and was deployed on GlassFish successfully without the previous error . Hope this workaround helps others

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of error is related to hibernate cache configuration:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException:
Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given;
please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath..
```

I would suggest to review/compare cache setting and check cache provider.

Comment: i didn't change anything in the `DataSource` file only the configuration of the DB and here is the part of cache `cache.use_second_level_cache = true
 cache.use_query_cache = false
 cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
  singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
  flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context`

Comment: So, you are using second level cache. You can try to turn off it by setting cache.use_second_level_cache = false or removing all cache properties. If you really want to use second level cache, you have to configure it properly, e.g. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/integrations/grails.html

Comment: i didn't  add anything to this part this what was generated by the Grails

Comment: commented the cache block in the file , and tried to deploy again but still getting the same errors.